# System.NullReferenceException Xamarin Maps

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm getting a NullException when will display the map, but can not detect;
I tried to change the name of the maps, locazation, etc., but without success.
You may be able to identify where is my mistake, please help me!

```
    public partial class LocationPage : ContentPage
    {
        public Clinica _clinica;

        public LocationPage(Clinica clinica)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Clinica = clinica;
            SetupMap();
        }



        public Clinica Clinica
        {
            get
            {
                return _clinica;
            }

            set
            {
                _clinica = value;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            // Typically, is preferable to call into the viewmodel for OnAppearing() logic to be performed,
            // but we're not doing that in this case because we need to interact with the Xamarin.Forms.Map property on this Page.
            // In the future, the Map type and it's properties may get more binding support, so that the map setup can be omitted from code-behind.
            SetupMap();
        }

        void SetupMap()
        {
            if (Device.OS != TargetPlatform.WinPhone && Device.OS != TargetPlatform.Windows)
            {
                var pin = new Pin()
                {
                    Type = PinType.Place,
                    Position = new Position(Clinica.Latitude, Clinica.Longitude),
                    Label = Clinica.Nome

                };

                clinicaMap.Pins.Clear();

                clinicaMap.Pins.Add(pin);

                clinicaMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(pin.Position, Distance.FromMiles(10)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LocationPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
             x:Class="CartaoDeTodos.View.LocationPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <maps:Map x:Name="clinicaMap"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

[image: Erro]

[image]

[image]

Comment: this may be unrelated, but you are calling SetupMaps() twice.  Have you tried "Break" when the exception dialog comes up, and examining the stack trace?

Comment: Two suspects: the `clinica` constructor parameter or the `clinicaMap.Pins`. Yes please use break points, it should be easy to find out.

Comment: I've edited the post to better understanding.
The error happens when I leave the maps code in the xaml file.

Comment: Post the exception text, not the screenshot. You can get the full text using `Exception.ToString()`. This includes the call stack which will show where the exception actually occured. BTW this screenshot appears when exceptions are thrown in external libraries. Exceptions thrown from your own code include the details

Comment: I had to put another print because I can not catch the exception in a try catch. The error occurs right after that line and no longer has any code train depot

Comment: The problem was solved. (Always make sure your shared libraries are the same version). Tks!